# How to assign the multiple users to a Custom object?(in Salesforce)

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I made a custom object called Job Requisition that has records I would like to be able to assign to only Recruiter profile Users so they could view their access. I created a lookup from this object to the user. Is there a way to assign multiple users to this record other than Public groups?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I happened across your question while looking of ran answer to a similar issue I'm having. The best answer I've been able to find is apparently a junction object.
The best description I've found, and I've found lots of descriptions, is at the link below.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252144/allow-a-custom-field-to-select-multiple-users-in-salesforce-lightning

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).